# "Quick Install Gem" not working on RubyMine

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, rubymine

I've just done a fresh install of RubyMine 4.5 in order to get a quickstart on Rails dev.

Whenever I try and install any Gem using the **Tools > Quick Install Gem...** command, I get the following error (below is specific to the flickraw gem)

> Failed to Install Gems
>
> Following gems were not installed:
>
> flickraw(0.9.6): While executing gem ...
>
> (Errno::EACCESS)
>
> Permission denied - /Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache/flickraw-0.9.6.gem

I guess I get that it's a permissions error...but why is it happening, shouldn't this just work? And how do I fix it?

I'm running this on the latest version of OSX Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had similar problems before, it turned out to be caused by sudo being the owner of some gems installed in that rvm ruby installation I was using. I guess I installed something with sudo by accident, I dunno-- but go check in `/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache` and `/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems` and see if sudo owns `cache/flickraw-0.9.6.gem` or any folders in `gems` and if needed change the owner and group back to you ... I actually had so many messed up I opted to just remove and rebuild that ruby.

Comment: +1 Thanks chrixian, I did start with a rather messed up install, I'll do a rebuild, thanks for your help!

Comment: I had a similar problem when trying to get RubyMine to install the debugger gem et. al. Fixed rbenv ownership with this: sudo chown -R ``whoami`` .rbenv/